# Why some hex values are represented as symbols when struck.pack values printed out?

Tags: python, struct, hex, pack

In my previous question ([Reading serial interface with Python returns distorted data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60344435/882647)) I asked why data appears distorted because it does not look 16 bytes as expected. Later I found out that the data is actually complete.

But it's still unclear to me why the hexadecimal values are represented as symbols when I `struct.pack` them, but not like on the picture from the logic analyzer?

[image]

```
>>> struct.pack('f', 1.0)
b'\x00\x00\x80?'
>>> struct.pack('f', 2.0)
b'\x00\x00\x00@'
>>> struct.pack('f', 3.0)
b'\x00\x00@@'
>>> struct.pack('f', 4.0)
b'\x00\x00\x80@'
```

Comment: If the byte value corresponds to a printing character, the string shows that character. Otherwise it shows the hex escape code.

Comment: `b'\x00\x00\x80?' == b'\x00\x00\x80\x3f'` because `chr(0x3f)` is `?`

Comment: @Barmar do you know why is that? It seems to me quite unreasonable, as I am not printing it as string.

Comment: @stardust it seems a little confusing in this case, but we often get bytes from networks or files and it's really convenient in those cases when the printable characters are represented as characters rather than hex -- i.e. `b'hello'` vs `b'\0x68\0x65\0x6c\0x6c\0x6f'`

Comment: The *purpose* of `struct.pack` is only to convert raw byte values (and other types) into a raw byte string, and printing such a byte array offers a basic translation for the screen only, What you do with that array is totally up to you; if you want to see its contents in hex, then print it out as such.

Comment: @usr2564301 I thought it is easier to see directly when you are typing. Well, certainly it is. Thanks!